How to convert the form of a solution from solve {x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> Sqrt[2]} into a list form {1, 1, Sqrt[2]}?
How to convert the form of a solution from solve as follows:
 {x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> Sqrt[2]}
into a list form
{1, 1, Sqrt[2]}?

The canonical way is {x, y, z} /. {x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> Sqrt[2]}.

(-1) After asking 247 undeleted questions, you still don't learn anything about the usage of /., not to mention basic list manipulation.

sol = {x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> Sqrt[2]};

Some other possibilities
Using Cases
Cases[(_ -> v_) :> v] @ sol

Using ReplaceAll
sol /. Rule[_, v_] :> v

Using Query
Query[All, 2] @ sol

Using Map
Map[Last] @ sol

All produce

{1, 1, Sqrt[2]}


Try
{x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> Sqrt[2]}[[All, 2]]

or
{x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> Sqrt[2]} // Values


If you used Solve to get these solutions, you can avoid the need for post-processing the result by using SolveValues instead.

Adding to what eldo said, I really like manual pattern matching even for very annoying cases. For your case:
sol = {x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> Sqrt[2]};
Replace[sol, {x -> a_, y -> b_, z -> c_} :> {a, b, c}]

But let's say something very annoying that needs counting levels or trial and error, I just copy the original list and paste in the second argument of  Replace and replace the parts I want with variables:
annoyingsol = {{{{{x -> 1}}}}, y -> 1, z -> Sqrt[2]};
Replace[annoyingsol, {{{{{x -> a_}}}}, y -> b_, z -> c_} :> {a, b, c}]

